# Lambda function is not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRole

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function in account A trying to access resources from account B. Created a new lambda role with basic execution with access to upload logs to cloud watch.

Here's my function code in Python 3.7:

```
import boto3

allProfiles = ['account2']

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::2222222222:role/role-on-source-account",
        RoleSessionName="account2"
    )

    for profiles in allProfiles:
        print("\nusing profile %s" % profiles)
        newMethod..
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Also modified the trust policy of the assumed role in account B as mentioned in documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

> ERROR: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole
>   operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::11111111:assumed-role/lambda-role/lambda-function is not
>   authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource:
>   arn:aws:iam::2222222222:role/role-on-source-account"

Note: I am able to run this in my local successfully but not in lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what we have is:

- Your (your own *trusted* account) accountA need to assume a specific role in the AccountB account
- A role in the AccountB (the *trusting* account) that your lambda is going to access a, let's say a bucket on.
- AccountBBucket

You mentioned you had Basic execution for your lambda and that alone would not be enough...

Solution:

1. Create a role "UpdateBucket": 
   you need to establish trust between AccountB(account ID number:999) and AccountA.
   Create an IAM role and define the AccountA as a trusted entity, specify a permission policy that allows trusted users to update the AccountB_resource(AccountBBucket).

   We Are in AccountA now

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
         "Resource": "*"
       },
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "s3:ListBucket",
           "s3:GetBucketLocation"
          ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucket"
       },
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "s3:GetObject",
           "s3:PutObject",
           "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucket/*"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
2. Grant Access:

   we will now use the role we created earlier, the (UpdateBucket) role
   This needs to be added to your AccountB permissions

   We are now in AccountB now:

   `{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::999:role/UpdateBucket"
     }
   }`

   Note that the 999 above is AccountB account Id and the UpdateBucket is the role that was created in AccountA

   This would create the trust you need for your lambda to access the bucket on AccountB

More info on here:
[Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

Comment: as mentioned in documentation  "Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles", how to get credentials:access_key, secret_key and session_id in lambda?

Comment: Your user/lambda needs to assume the role. Read the link I sent before and when you get to "Using AssumeRole (AWS API)" continue with this link: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

Comment: sure thing bud, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 10):

> Created a new lambda role with basic execution with access to upload logs to cloud watch

Basic execution role for lambda is not enough. You need to **explicitly allow your function** to  `AssumeRole`. The following statement in your execution role should help:

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "sts:AssumeRole"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iam::2222222222:role/role-on-source-account"
  ]
}
```

Comment: along with this change, I've added trust relationship and now I'm not getting unauthorized error but not able to get ec2 data from account B, getting data only from account A.

Comment: Maybe something with your function itself. In the question, the issue was `AssumeRole` permission, and the issue seems to be solved. Maybe can make new question specifically tailored to the new issue you have?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Wait for a few minutes.

**Reason**: The returned STS information is cached. It could persist for some time on the container. To remove cache locally (on a mac), you could run

```
rm -rf ~/.aws/cli/cache/
```